# prevent downloading video using session session with php - not working in safari browser

Tags: php, html, video

I found a script consisting of three parts that I found as a result of my research on the internet in order to hide the video source. I have run this code which consists of three php pages but I am having some problems.
First of all, when I encrypt, the video is not watched on apple devices and safari. It can't be watched on iphone or mobile opera.
but it can be watched from android devices and google chorome opera, no problem.

My other problem is that I cannot specify the file path in a directory in index.php. It doesn't work if I put the file in a directory.

I need to upload the file to both the php files directory and the videos directory at the same time.
I would be very happy if you could help me with this subject.

```
<?php 
  /**
  * index.php - The Entry File
  **/

  session_start();
  session_regenerate_id();
  // We will tell the next file that we have a token set using session
  $_SSEION['setToken'] = true;
  // We will tell the next file that we have a token set using session
  $_SSEION['setToken'] = true;

  // The filename... You can get that from a $_GET variable and store it here
  $token = "vid.mp4";

  // We will be encrypting the video name using session id as key ans AES128 as the           
  $token_encrypted = openssl_encrypt($token, "aes128", session_id());
  ?>

  <video width="320" height="240" controls="">
  <source src="video.php?vid=<?php echo $token_encrypted; ?>">
  </source></video>

 <?php
 **/
 video.php
 session_start();
 // Get Token
 $token = $_GET['vid'];
 // Get Current Session ID
 $prev= session_id();
 // Test the session variable token is set
 if(isset($_SESSION['setToken']))
  {
 // This was a one time token and this is your security
 unset($_SESSION['setToken']);
 // Now we will re-encrypt the token
 $token = openssl_decrypt($token, "aes128", session_id());
 // Now Regenerate the session id
 session_regenerate_id();
 // Now re-encrypt the token with a key combination of both new and old ids
 $token = openssl_encrypt($token, "aes128", $prev.session_id());
 }
else
 {
 //If token was not matched, we have changed the id therefore the next script will           not be able to decrypt the token
 session_regenerate_id(true);
  }
 header("Location: access.php?id=".$prev."&vid=".$token);
 ?>


<?php
/**
* access.php - The main serving file which will server the video
**/
session_start();

// Decrypt the Token to get back the video file name
$token = openssl_decrypt($_GET['vid'], "aes128", $_GET['id'].session_id());

// Check if file exists
if(file_exists("videos/".$token))
{
 // Another important point here is a session id regeneration
session_regenerate_id(true);  

 $file = $token;
 $file_size = filesize($file);
 $file_pointer = fopen($file, "rb");
 $data = fread($file_pointer, $file_size);
 header("Content-type: video/mp4");

 echo $data;
 }
 else {
 echo "Error: File Does not exists";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: This is a misguided approach. It just won't work.

Comment: so where is the error and how can i fix it? What is your suggestion?

Comment: The two scripts are trying to hide the real file location from your user. I believe one of the ways to fix it is to open a pop-up box (instead of a direct video tag) to render the video .

Comment: Hm, what is stopping a user from running a screen-recording software to capture the video?

Comment: My problem is that I cannot play video in apple safari browser, is it because of openssl?

Comment: Here, the pages that are nested with open ssl prevent the direct download feature of the video. But I can't prevent the video from being copied with screen recording!